# PHP create recursive file structure

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in a php web application and i need create a file structure based on a mysql table with following structure:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| tPages                                |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| Id | PageName        | IsDir | Parent | 
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 1  | Index           | 0     | 0      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 2  | Dir1            | 1     | 0      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 3  | Sub1            | 1     | 2      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 4  | Page1_in_Sub1   | 0     | 3      | 
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 5  | Page_in_Dir1    | 0     | 2      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| 6  | Page2_in_Sub1   | 0     | 3      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
```

so column "parent" refers to the "Id" to the same table and i have the next php function for recursive creation, but not work as i want:

```
function  recurse($pages)
{
  foreach($pages as $page)
  {

    if($page->IsDir == 0){
      // code for create the file:
      $html = "some html";
      $myFile = $page->PageName.'.html'; // or .php
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("error");
      fwrite($fh, $html);
      fclose($fh);
    }else{
      $dirname = strtolower($page->PageName);
      $dirname = str_replace(' ','_',$dirname);
      mkdir($page->PageName, 0755, true);
      // get childs for this dir.
      // $pages = "Select * From tPages Where tPages.Id = $page->Id";
      $this->recurse($pages);
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me, when i pass resultset to "recurse" function this create files in the last directory. Thanks.

Comment: my function create all files in the last directory but each file have a parent and the function should put each file in your parent directory, now the function create each dir correctly but the files are created in the last dir. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include your query for the resultset and code calling `recurse`.

Comment: Also your example is not using recursion, at least not in a way we can see, because instead of calling `recurse` it's calling `$this->recurseEsIntra()`. Ultimately, you'll need to get another result set from the your `$page` row that has the new matching pages before calling the next iteration of `recurse()`. As it stands, I see no way for it to iterate recursively since passing `$pages` without some type of identifier to another function would not allow it to alter the heirarchy of the query.

Comment: sorry this is an error on my exmple, these is not the real code is only a reference of the real, i forgot change "$this->recurseEsIntra($pages)" to "$this->recurse($pages)" but in a few moments i edit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing repeated SQL queries, this will rely on loading all of the data and processing it in one go.  The data is assumed to be in order (as in creating a file that the directory it's in is already before it in the list.

```
// Test data
$pages = [(object)["Id" => 1, "PageName" => "p1", "IsDir" => 0, "Parent" => 0],
    (object)["Id" => 2, "PageName" => "d1", "IsDir" => 1, "Parent" => 0],
    (object)["Id" => 3, "PageName" => "p2", "IsDir" => 0, "Parent" => 2]
];

// Work out the path for an entry.
// Change $basePath to be the path you need to start the structure in.
// (No trailing /)
function getPath ( $page, $pagesIndex, $basePath = 'faq' ) {
    if ( $page->Parent == 0 )   {
        $path = $basePath."/";
        if ( $page->IsDir == 1) {
            $path .= $page->PageName;
        }
    }
    else    {
        $path = $pagesIndex[$page->Parent]->path;
    }
    return $path;
}

// Re-index the data so that the Id is the index into the array
$pagesIndex = array_column($pages, null, "Id");
foreach ( $pagesIndex as $page ) {
    if ( $page->IsDir == 1 )    {
        $path = getPath($page, $pagesIndex);
        // If directory doesn't already exist - create it
        if (!file_exists($path) && !is_dir($path)) {
            mkdir ( $path );
        }
        // Store the path in the object so that sub folders/files know where to start
        $page->path = $path;
    }
    else    {
        // code for create the file:
        $html = "some html";
        // Make sure the path is part of the filename to be creates
        $myFile = getPath($page, $pagesIndex)."/".$page->PageName.'.html'; // or .php
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("error");
        fwrite($fh, $html);
        fclose($fh);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, not work properly but clarify my ideas very well, and i could solve my problem, **you're the best!**.